# Declaration suffix for decimal type

Tags: c#, .net

If I want to use a decimal literal in code, I have seen that there exists the m-suffix (where m stands for money). Is this appropriate for any decimals or is there a more general assignment (d stands for double, that is for sure not the right thing although a direct conversion is supported).

```
object decimalValue=2m;
```

Please note, I took the object-assignment as example, because in the case of ...

```
decimal decimalValue=2;
```

... it's implicitly clear that 2 should be interpreted as decimal through the compiler.

**m** seems to be ok, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx) uses it as example for the decimal type.

Comment: M could stand for money but it could just be the next available letter of the word “decimal” because D is used for double and E is used as the exponential symbol as in ‘1E06’ for example.

Comment: Thank you Caltor for solving that mystery. So m is not for mystery anymore.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Documented in the [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types), chapter 2.4.4:

```
float f = 1.2f;
double d = 1.2d;
uint u = 2u;
long l = 2L;
ulong ul = 2UL;
decimal m = 2m;
```

Nothing for int, byte, sbyte, short, ushort.

Comment: Whilst not a suffix, we can also declare a character with `char c = 'a'` using apostrophes around the character.

Comment: You can also refer to this Doc, which is more user-friendly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types-table

Comment: So there is not even a US for ushort?  :-)

Answer (score 25):

Without a suffix, a numerical real literal will be a Double. The m suffix specifies that a numeric real literal should be a Decimal.

This is actually important to know, since arithmetic on floating point values (such as Double) is imprecise. For instance:

```
object decimalValue=(5.32 + 2.23);
```

Here, decimalValue will actually contain a Double, with the unexpected value of 7.5500000000000007! If I want 7.55, I could do this:

```
object decimalValue=(5.32m + 2.23m);
```

To answer your question about whether there is a more general suffix, m is the *only* suffix for Decimal in C#. It might stand for money as you mentioned, but they had do use something other than d, since that's used by Double!

Further reading: [decimal (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I have seen and put the msdn-link into my question exactly as you entered your answer. However I accepted the post of Hans Passant because there is a nice list that will help a lot to people who will come to this post because of the suffixes. But thanks definitively.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to **Declare Decimal in C#**

```
decimal firstMoney = 141.28m;
```

**O/P:** 141.28

```
decimal secondMoney = 100.00m;
```

**O/P:** 100

For more refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

Hope helps someone.

Comment: @Thomas , i understand but i just tried to give short answer for those who searching for declaring decimal, should i delete the post ? , you think its not useful ?

Comment: *I* see it as not useful *but* I'm far from perfect and it *may* help others. If, in a second read you find it not useful, then you can delete it. If you think that it'll help someone, leave it as is :)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Personally, don't see what this adds that [Hans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3271831/692942) doesn't already cover.

Comment: is it possible to do this with a variable? For example: variableM, rather then 1,25M

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder It should work if `variableM` has decimal value in it.