# C# - Numeric Suffixes

Tags: c#, numeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaration suffix for decimal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271791/declaration-suffix-for-decimal-type)

Hey everyone,

In the following snippet of code; RewardValue is a decimal:

```
dto.RewardValue = 1.5;
```

Now, this gives me the following error:

"Cannot convert source type double to target type decimal"

Makes sense, and is easily fixable by changing that line of code to this:

```
dto.RewardValue = 1.5m;
```

Now, the "m" converts that to a decimal and all is good.

Does anybody know of somewhere where I could find a list of all those "m" type operators?  (and if you could let me know what the proper term for those are, it would be greatly appreciated)

**EDIT:**  Thanks to HCL and MartyIX for letting me know that these are referred to as "suffixes"

Comment: The answer to this is found at the "dupe" question, but the question asked there is much more targeted. It asks explicitly just for the decimal suffix (`decimal m = 2m;`), and this asks for a list of all "numeric suffixes". Fwiw, 2¢, etc.

Answer (score 33):

I believe the term you're looking for is "suffix".

Examples:

```
1;    // int
1.0;  // double
1.0f; // float
1.0m; // decimal
1u;   // uint
1L;   // long
1UL;  // ulong
```

Answer (score 25):

It's a pretty small list, really.

```
F:  float
D:  double
U:  uint
L:  long
UL: ulong
M:  decimal
```

Of course a plain integral value by itself is interpreted as an `int`, unless it's too big to be an `int` in which case it's a `long`, unless it's too big for a `long` in which case it's a `ulong`. If it's too big for a `ulong`, you can't use it as a literal (as far as I know).

A value with a decimal point in it is automatically interpreted (as you found out for yourself) as a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix - they call it simply `numeric suffixes`
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(VS.71).aspx - also suffix here)

> Suffix type: unsigned int
>
> Character:   U
>
> Example:     uint x = 100U;
>
> Suffix type: long
>
> Character:   L
>
> Example:     long x = 100L;
>
> Suffix type: unsigned long
>
> Character:   UL
>
> Example:     ulong x = 100UL;
>
> Suffix type: float
>
> Character:   F
>
> Example:     float x = 100F;
>
> Suffix type: double
>
> Character:   D
>
> Example:     double x = 100D;
>
> Suffix type: decimal
>
> Character:   M
>
> Example:     decimal x = 100M;

Comment: Is there a suffix for `short` or `Int16`?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not. If it were, it would be mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's called a "numeric litteral":
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx