# Trying to Assign a Large Number at Compile Time

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, checked, unchecked

The following two operations are identical.  However, MaxValues1 will not compile due to a "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode."  Can someone please explain what is going on with the compiler and how I can get around it without have to use a hard-coded value as in MaxValues2?

```
public const ulong MaxValues1 = 0xFFFF * 0xFFFF * 0xFFFF;

public const ulong MaxValues2 = 0xFFFD0002FFFF;
```

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag...

Answer (score 4):

To get unsigned literals, add `u` suffix, and to make them long a `l` suffix. i.e. you need `ul`.

If you really want the overflow behavior, you can add `unchecked` to get `unchecked(0xFFFF * 0xFFFF * 0xFFFF)` but that's likely not what you want. You get the overflow because the literals get interpreted as `Int32` and not as `ulong`, and `0xFFFF * 0xFFFF * 0xFFFF` does not fit a 32 bit integer, since it is approximately 2^48.

```
public const ulong MaxValues1 = 0xFFFFul * 0xFFFFul * 0xFFFFul;
```

Comment: 'and thus doesn't fit a long'. Might want to change that statement?

Comment: @KendallFrey I already reformulated that part, and wasn't sure if I wrote doesn't fit a long or doesn't fit an int. long is of course wrong.

Answer (score 2):

By default, integer literals are of type `int`. You can add the 'UL' suffix to change them to `ulong` literals.

```
public const ulong MaxValues1 = 0xFFFFUL * 0xFFFFUL * 0xFFFFUL;

public const ulong MaxValues2 = 0xFFFD0002FFFFUL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its actually not a `ulong` until you assign it at the end, try

```
public const ulong MaxValues1 = (ulong)0xFFFF * (ulong)0xFFFF * (ulong)0xFFFF;
```

i.e. in `MaxValues1` you are multiplying 3 32bit ints together which overflows as the result is implied as another 32bit int, when you cast the op changes to multiplying 3 `ulongs` together which wont overflow as you are inferring the result is a `ulong`

```
(ulong)0xFFFF * 0xFFFF * 0xFFFF;

0xFFFF * (ulong)0xFFFF * 0xFFFF;
```

also work as the result type is calculated based on the largest type

but

```
0xFFFF * 0xFFFF * (ulong)0xFFFF;
```

won't work as the first 2 will overflow the int

Comment: That got it working.  The 0xFFFF's are actually hard coded constants within another package whose source I cannot change.  Adding the ulong's seem to have fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: @George, if this solved your problem you should click the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add numeric suffixes 'UL' to each of the numbers. Otherwise, C# considers them as Int32.

[C# - Numeric Suffixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569695/c-sharp-numeric-suffixes)