# Rounding Problems for C# Decimal

Tags: c#

```
Decimal a = Decimal.Round((Decimal)3.5 * (Decimal)0.01,2);
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
a = Decimal.Round((Decimal)4.5 * (Decimal)0.01,2);
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());

a = Decimal.Round(Decimal.Multiply((Decimal)3.5, (Decimal)0.01), 2);
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
a = Decimal.Round(Decimal.Multiply((Decimal)4.5, (Decimal)0.01), 2);
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

Why are all the message boxes showing 0.04 when the inputs are different?

Comment: It's not exactly the same as the duplicate, but it's essentially [the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Decimal_Round_System_Decimal_System_MidpointRounding_) as with `Math.Round`.

Comment: FYI - instead of `(Decimal)4.5` - its easier to write `4.5M` or `4.5m` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569695/c-sharp-numeric-suffixes

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behavior. As the default MidpointRounding mode is ToEven, both 0.035 and 0.045 are rounded to 0.04.

Answer (score 1):

Bacause it uses [bankers rounding](http://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding):

> two nearest integers are rounded to the nearest even integer

Specify Round rules:

```
Decimal.Round((Decimal)4.5 * (Decimal)0.01, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

From the following [post](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2017/01/use-bankers-rounding-and-normal-rounding-in-c/):

> Statistically half of a sample of numbers are rounded up and half are
>   rounded down

This is how money are rounded to compensate summation error in financial balance computations.