# Array values can't produce a double value

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my code where the average is a whole number even though I specify it as a double data type. What could be the problem?

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;
class TemperaturesComparison
{
   static void Main()
   {
     int[] temp = new int[5];
     int i = 0;
     while (i < 5)
     {
       int eachTemp = int.Parse(ReadLine());
       if (eachTemp < -30 || eachTemp > 130) continue; //skips 
       temp[i] = eachTemp;
       i++;
     }
     
     if (temp[0] < temp[1] && temp[1] < temp[2] && temp[2] < temp[3] && temp[3] < temp[4]) WriteLine("Getting warmer");
     else if (temp[0] > temp[1] && temp[1] > temp[2] && temp[2] > temp[3] && temp[3] > temp[4]) WriteLine("Getting cooler");
     else WriteLine("It's a mixed bag");
     
     foreach(int number in temp)
     {
     Console.Write(number + " ");
     }
     double average = temp.Sum()/5;
     WriteLine("");
     WriteLine(average);
     
   }
}
```

For instance, **I input: 88 99 78 86 77**

**The average is 85 instead of 85.6**

Comment: Instead of 5 use 5.0

Comment: Thank You. I didn't know C# was this type-sensitive. Just transitioned from Python

Comment: Type sensitive you could say 5 is an int so any operation with only ints will result in an int. By using 5.0 you have declared an double and any operation with a double will result in a double. Could have also used 5D to make it double.

Comment: See here for a list of suffixes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569695/c-sharp-numeric-suffixes

Comment: See also: [The C# type system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/). It says: *"C# is a strongly typed language. [...]"*.

Answer (score 5):

The number is converted to `double` after the integer division (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-)) is performed (so the division result will not have decimal part), you need to convert one of the arguments to `double` before the division:

```cs
double average = (double)temp.Sum()/5;
```

or just change the divisor to be `5.0` (which will [become of type `double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types))

```cs
double average = temp.Sum()/5.0;
```

Also note that you can just use LINQ's [`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=net-6.0) which has return type of `double` for overload accepting enumerable of `int`:

```
var average = temp.Average();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the array of `double` type instead of `int` it will work as expected. Just do this :

```
double[] temp = new double[5];
```

**Output**

[image]