# How do I cast value without the braces in LINQ?

Tags: linq

When I output this code, I get { Price: 1446 } when I only want the number without the braces. Is there a way to do this? Also, once I get the price value, I want to convert it to a **decimal**. Is there a way to do this?

```
var flightPrice = (from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata.xml")).Elements("flight")
                           where (string)f.Element("flightnumber") == FlightNumber
                              && (string)f.Element("destinationairportsymbol") == Destination
                           select new { Price = (Int32)f.Element("price") }
                           ).SingleOrDefault();

lblPrice.Text = flightPrice.ToString();
```

Comment: Could you show us the XML file you're parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` is creating an anonymous type with a single property: Price. If all you want is the *actual* price (and as a float), change your select to

```
// select new { Price = (Int32)f.Element("price") }
select (float)(int)f.Element("price")
```

However, it is not recommended that you use a `float` to deal with something financial like a *price.* The `decimal` data type is the preferred type for such a value.

```
select (decimal)f.Element("price")
```

Comment: Yes I would like to use decimal to two decimal places. How do I go about using it?

Comment: @multiv123, updated the answer, but it is simply casting to decimal instead of float.

Comment: i need to store it as a decimal value because i need to compute a tax value using it.

Comment: By casting inside the `select` statement and using `Single`, your use of the `var` keyword means that the compiler will automatically infer the type of the variable to be `decimal`. You can also explicitly make it so by simply declaring `decimal flightPrice = ...` instead of `var flightPrice = `.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, I'm trying to compute the tax as decimal tax = flightPrice * 0.35; but I'm getting a squiggly line error. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @multiv123, the compiler is inferring `0.35` as type `double`. To force the compiler to consider it a decimal, write it as `0.35m`. See this question for more on numeric suffixes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271791/declaration-suffix-for-decimal-type/3271831#3271831

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do:

```
lblPrice.Text = flightPrice.Price.ToString();
```

You can also do this:

```
// omited the first 3 lines of your linq statement...
 select (Int32)f.Element("price")
 ).SingleOrDefault();
```

in which case `flightPrice` will be of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Either put `select (Int32)f.Element("price")` instead of `select new { Price = (Int32)f.Element("price") }`

or

```
lblPrice.Text = flightPrice.Price.ToString();
```