# Calculation the area of a triangle

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to calculate the area of a triangle, with the values 2, 2 and 1. When I do the calculation in my pocket calculator I get 0.97, but in C# it's 0. I guess it has something to do about the rounding of the decimals, but I have changed the last value from i and up, but still get 0 as the result! What am I doing wrong? Help preciated! Thanks!

```
double i = (valueA + valueB + valueC) / 2;
return Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(i * (i - valueA) * (i - valueB) * (i - valueC)),1);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Divide by `2.0` or `2d` or `2D`

**Reason:** Integer Division gives only integer part and removes the fraction part.

`2` is integer. `2.0` is double value.

```
double i = (valueA + valueB + valueC) / 2.0;
```

OR

```
double i = (valueA + valueB + valueC) / 2d;
```

OR

```
double i = (valueA + valueB + valueC) / 2D;
```

Second line remains the same

```
return Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(i * (i - valueA) * (i - valueB) * (i - valueC)),1);
```

Comment: Or explicitly use the `D` suffix, e.g. `2D`.

Comment: Either are fine. I prefer 2D since it makes it more obvious as a suffix.

Comment: Thanks! Is the 'd' in 2d decimal? What are this letters called, I have seen al kinds of letters in combinations with numbers in code and I just want to learn more about it?

Comment: Yes d in 2d is double. Sometimes we use `f` which means float. They are called Suffixes.

Comment: @3D-kreativ They are termed [`Suffixes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271791/declaration-suffix-for-decimal-type/3271831#3271831)

Comment: Ok, but is there a common name for using this letters in combination of numbers? I would like to know if there a other usefull letters to use?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal for decimal its `m` and not `d`

Answer (score 2):

Please try `(valueA + valueB + valueC) / 2.0`.