# the best overloaded match for object.object has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, class, object, properties

I am trying to create a new object of type Invoice. I pass in the necessary parameters in the correct order.

However, it is telling me that I have included invalid arguments. I might be overlooking something very simple here, but maybe someone can point it out.

I am working on homework, however the Invoice.cs file was included for use with the project.

The only solution I am seeking is why my object will not accept the values. I have never had an issue with objects before.

Here is the code I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Invoice myInvoice = new Invoice(83, "Electric sander", 7, 57.98);
}
```

And here is the actual Invoice.cs file:

```
// Exercise 9.3 Solution: Invoice.cs
// Invoice class.
public class Invoice
{
   // declare variables for Invoice object
   private int quantityValue;
   private decimal priceValue;

   // auto-implemented property PartNumber
   public int PartNumber { get; set; }

   // auto-implemented property PartDescription
   public string PartDescription { get; set; }

   // four-argument constructor
   public Invoice( int part, string description,
      int count, decimal pricePerItem )
   {
      PartNumber = part;
      PartDescription = description;
      Quantity = count;
      Price = pricePerItem;
   } // end constructor

   // property for quantityValue; ensures value is positive
   public int Quantity
   {
      get
      {
         return quantityValue;
      } // end get
      set
      {
         if ( value > 0 ) // determine whether quantity is positive
            quantityValue = value; // valid quantity assigned
      } // end set
   } // end property Quantity

   // property for pricePerItemValue; ensures value is positive
   public decimal Price
   {
      get
      {
         return priceValue;
      } // end get
      set
      {
         if ( value >= 0M ) // determine whether price is non-negative
            priceValue = value; // valid price assigned
      } // end set
   } // end property Price

   // return string containing the fields in the Invoice in a nice format
   public override string ToString()
   {
      // left justify each field, and give large enough spaces so
      // all the columns line up
      return string.Format( "{0,-5} {1,-20} {2,-5} {3,6:C}",
         PartNumber, PartDescription, Quantity, Price );
   } // end method ToString
} // end class Invoice
```

Comment: Try putting an 'M' after 57.98. As it is, that number is a double constant I believe and cannot convert to decimal, but 57.98M is a decimal constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is expecting a `decimal` parameter where as you are passing a `double` value (57.98).

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (see Remarks section),

> There are no implicit conversions between floating-point types and the
>   decimal type.

For decimals you should add suffix 'm' or 'M'

So, in your case, pass 57.98m instead of 57.98

> [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3271831/441860) lists all kinds of suffixes.

Comment: Ah. Thank you! I should stop staying up so late programming!