# Unexpected behavior between [Flags] enum : long vs [Flags] enum : ulong

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, enums, visual-studio-2013, enum-flags

**Compiles but shouldn't**

```
[Flags]
enum TransactionData : long  // 64 bits.  Last bit is sign bit, but I'm putting data there
{
    None = 0,
    Color1 = 1 << 63,
}
```

**Errors but shouldn't**

```
[Flags]
enum TransactionData : ulong  // 64 bits. No sign bit.  Not allowed to put data there
{
    None = 0,
    Color1 = 1 << 63,
}
```

Compiler Error Text:

> -2147483648 cannot be converted to a  ulong

**Question:**

I would expect the opposite to occur.  Can anyone explain why this is?

Also how I can print this flags attribute to a `byte[]` for inspection?

```
 var eee  = TransactionData.None | TransactionData.Color1
 // How do I convert eee to byte[]?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that `1 << 63` isn't a `ulong` or even a `long`. The compiler interprets it as an `int`. Observe the following example:

```
enum TransactionData : long
{
    None = 0,
    Color1 = 1 << 31,
    Color2 = 1 << 63,
}

Console.WriteLine(TransactionData.Color1 == TransactionData.Color2); // True
```

However, you can coerce the compiler into interpreting it as a `ulong` by adding `ul` to the end:

```
enum TransactionData : ulong
{
    None = 0,
    Color1 = 1ul << 63,
}
```

Although many people prefer using an upper case `L` because the lowercase `l` looks a lot like a number `1`. A full list of what suffixes are supported by the compiler can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3271831/1715579).

Also, I should point out that `1ul << 63` is actually *64* bits wide (it's one bit, shifted by 63 bits).

Comment: Funny thing, I've been working with C# for 8 years, and just learned the concept of appending letters to cast a number to a different types.  Wonder how many people are in the same boat as me.

Comment: Do you know how I can cast this ULong enum to a Byte[] perchance? (ps will accept yours no matter what in 6 min.. when the timeout expires.

Comment: @makerofthings7 See the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class, e.g. `BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)TransactionData.Color1)`