# calling Extention Method with 'this double' in C#

Tags: c#, double, call, this, extension-methods

im converting string to code for runtime compile using code dom,
so i really need to know if its possible to call static method with 'this double', before i manage to write more complex code to produce correct string

i have method

```
public static double Test(this double x)
{
   //some code here...
}
```

and i want to call it like

```
double d = 5.Test();//Compiler Error: Cannot resolve symbol Test
```

i know this is possible for strings but i cant do the same thing for double.
how can i do this
also if its not possible why its possible for string?
thanks for help.

Comment: `5` is an integer. Use `5.0`

Comment: `5` does not have type `double`, it has type `int`. What error (if any) do you get when actually trying it with `double`?

Comment: oh thanks. i didnt notice 5 is integer ...fixed problem using ((double)5) also 5.0 worked well. tnx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

declare your `5` as a double, right now it's an integer.

```
double d = 5D.Test();
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271791/declaration-suffix-for-decimal-type/3271831#3271831) the list of numeric suffixes C# uses.