# double or decimal when calculating percent

Tags: c#

Based on this thread [decimal vs double!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when), decimal is always used for money. What is the proper way to define percent? like TaxPercent? If it's double then for calculating amount * 8% (double) you would have to cast it. 
What's the proper way to define percent value (ie tax) and what would the calculation be.

Comment: Because percent is actually unit-less, I would think it depends on what you want to take the percentage of. If you want it from a money amount, then I would take the type of the amount, in casu decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 'm' suffix to specify a literal as a decimal.  So it must be 0.08m to ensure a double doesn't creep into the calculation.

```
 decimal tax = amount * 0.08m;
```

You'll find a list of valid suffix characters in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3271831/17034).

Comment: lets say you had to assign tax value of 8 to a variable: decimal taxPercent = (8 / 100); tax would now be 0 which is incorrect

Comment: Don't write bad code, that's an integer division.  You should now know to write `8m / 100m`.