# Math.Round bug 81.725 MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero = 81.72

Tags: c#, math

I have a bug with Math.Round with no explanation.
When I make

```
Math.Round(81.725, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

The result is 81,72 but when I make the same with Decimal.Round

```
Decimal.Round(81.725M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

The result is 81,73

I d'ont understand why, have you an solution to use Math.Round systematically ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when|

Do you know what's difference between Decimal and Floating Point (double, float)?

Comment: You problem is not because of `Math.Round` vs `Decimal.Round`. It's because your input value is double in one case and decimal in the other. Try `Math.Round(81.725M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);` and you'll see the results are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be talking about *bugs* before understanding how `double` works, and the differences with `decimal` that explain the behavior you are seeing.

A double is the best approximation of a real number with the following structure:

```
number = sign * mantissa * 2 ^ exponent
```

Therefore, the number `81.725,` when represented as a `double`, is really:

```
1 * 2875442808959795 * 2^-45 = 81,724999999999994315658113919199
```

Now you should understand why `Math.Round(81.725, 2)` resolves to `81.72` and not `81.73`.

This doesn't happen with `decimal` because `decimal`, contrary to `double`, can exactly represent `81.725`. This is due to the fact that the scaling factor in `decimal` is a power of `10`.

This added precision obviously comes at a cost, in speed, space and range. When to choose one type or the other is well explained in a link to another SO question provided in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

The `M` suffix on second assignment below determines data type:

```
Math.Round(81.725, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // double, returns 81.72

Math.Round(81.725M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // decimal, returns 81.73

Decimal.Round(81.725M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // decimal, returns 81.73
```

By using that suffix, the given data type on second assignment treated as `decimal` instead of `double`, makes the rounding more precise.

The [MSDN documentation of Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx) already mention this difference:

> **Notes to Callers:**
>
> Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing
>   decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic
>   operations on floating-point values, in some cases the `Round(Double)`
>   method **may not appear to round midpoint values to the nearest even
>   integer.**

And there is further explanation for [Decimal.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This
>   kind of rounding is sometimes called round **half to even or banker's
>   rounding.** It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently
>   rounding a midpoint value in a single direction. It is equivalent to
>   calling the `Round(Decimal, MidpointRounding)` method with a mode
>   argument of `MidpointRounding.ToEven`.

In short, `decimal` uses IEEE-754 which uses consistent rounding for midpoint value, while `double` (and `float`) uses floating-point which has no finite binary representation.

Other reference:

[Declaration suffix for decimal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271791/declaration-suffix-for-decimal-type/3271831#3271831)